# Update values of form fields in db through My account/profile page

Tags: php, pdo

i am using below code for customer Registration & Login , it's working fine.

**db connection**

```
<?php
class Database
{

    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "dbname";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "helpme";
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection()
    {

        $this->conn = null;    
        try
        {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

**register**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';

$reg_user = new USER();

if($reg_user->is_logged_in()!="")
{
    $reg_user->redirect('home.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{   
    $uname = trim($_POST['txtuname']);
    $email = trim($_POST['txtemail']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['txtpass']);
    $cpass = trim($_POST['txtcpass']);
    $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
    $street_address = trim($_POST['street_address']);
    $street_address_2 = trim($_POST['street_address_2']);
    $city = trim($_POST['city']);
    $state = trim($_POST['state']);
    $zip_code = trim($_POST['zip_code']);
    $country = trim($_POST['country']);
    $code = md5(uniqid(rand()));

    $stmt = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userEmail=:email_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        $msg = "
              <div class='alert alert-error'>
                <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                    <strong>Sorry !</strong>  email allready exists , Please Try another one
              </div>
              ";
    }
    if($upass != $cpass){

    $msg = "passwords doesn't match";
}
    else
    {
        if($reg_user->register($uname,$email,$upass, $code, $phone, $street_address, $street_address_2 , $city , $state , $zip_code , $country ))
        {           
            $id = $reg_user->lasdID();      
            $key = base64_encode($id);
            $id = $key;

            $message = "                    
                        Hello $uname,
                        <br /><br />
                        Welcome to designer!<br/>
                        To complete your registration  please , just click following link<br/>
                        <br /><br />
                        <a href='http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]'.'verify.php?id=$id&code=$code'>Click HERE to Activate :)</a>

                        <br /><br />
                        Thanks,";

            $subject = "Confirm Registration";

            $reg_user->send_mail($email,$message,$subject); 
            $msg = "
                    <div class='alert alert-success'>
                        <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                        <strong>Success!</strong>  We've sent an email to $email.
                    Please click on the confirmation link in the email to create your account. 
                    </div>
                    ";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "sorry , Query could no execute...";
        }       
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body id="login">
    <div class="container">
                <?php if(isset($msg)) echo $msg;  ?>
      <form class="form-signin" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign Up</h2><hr />
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Username" name="txtuname" required />
        <input type="email" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address" name="txtemail" required />
        <input id="pass1"  type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" name="txtpass" required />
        <input id="pass2" type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="confirm Password" name="txtcpass" required />
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Telephone" name="phone"  />
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Street Address" name="street_address"  />
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Stree Address 2" name="street_address_2" />
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="city" name="city"  />
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="state" name="state"  />
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="zip code" name="zip_code"  />
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="country" name="country"  />
        <hr />

        <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" name="btn-signup" type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Sign Up" onclick="return comparePasswords()" />
        <a href="index.php" style="float:right;" class="btn btn-large">Sign In</a>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <script src="vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**class.user.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

class USER
{   

    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function lasdID()
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function register($uname,$email,$upass, $code, $phone, $street_address, $street_address_2 , $city , $state , $zip_code , $country)
    {
        try
        {                           
            $password = md5($upass);
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userEmail,userPass, tokenCode, phone, street_address, street_address_2 , city , state , zip_code , country) 
                                                         VALUES(:user_name, :user_mail, :user_pass, :active_code, :phone , :street_address, :street_address_2 , :city , :state , :zip_code , :country)");
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_name",$uname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_mail",$email);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_pass",$password);
            $stmt->bindparam(":active_code",$code);
            $stmt->bindparam(":phone",$phone);
            $stmt->bindparam(":street_address",$street_address);
            $stmt->bindparam(":street_address_2",$street_address_2);
            $stmt->bindparam(":city",$city);
            $stmt->bindparam(":state",$state);
            $stmt->bindparam(":zip_code",$zip_code);
            $stmt->bindparam(":country",$country);          
            $stmt->execute();   
            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function login($email,$upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userEmail=:email_id");
            $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
                {
                    if($userRow['userPass']==md5($upass))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header("Location: index.php?error");
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: index.php?inactive");
                    exit;
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: index.php?error");
                exit;
            }       
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }


    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function redirect($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
    }


}
```

**home.php** [ customer will redirect to this home/profile page after login]

```
<?php

//Initializing variable
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect('index.php');
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

in registration page we have name, email, city, zip....etc.

i need to provide an option for customer to update those fields in profile page.

once customer login, he will be redirect to profile/home page, in that page

**I want to display all form fields and provide a "edit" button and once he click on that button, he should be able to update the values of name, email....etc.**

i tried by adding below code, but not working for me.

**class.user.php**

```
public function update($uname,$email,$phone) {
        try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('UPDATE tbl_users SET userName = ?, userEmail = ?, phone = ? WHERE userID = ? ');
        $stmt->execute(array($uname,$email,$phone,$_SESSION['userID']));
        return $stmt->fetch();
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }
```

**home or profile [home.php ]**

```
$FORM['uname'] = "";
$FORM['txtuname'] = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// new data
$uname = $_POST['txtuname'];
$email = $_POST['txtemail'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$uid = (isset($_GET['userID']) ? intval($_GET['userID']) : -1);

// query
if ($uid->update($uname,$email,$phone,$userID)); {
    redirect('home.php');
}
}

<form action="home.php" method="POST">

Name<br>
<input type="text" name="txtuname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['txtuname'] ?>" /><br>
Email<br>
<input type="text" name="txtemail" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email'] ?>" /><br>
Phone<br>
<input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['phone'] ?>" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**its giving error : Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on a non-object in** line

```
if ($uid->update($uname,$email,$phone,$userID)); {
```

[image]

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. What exactly is the issue? I know that you want to "display all form fields and provide a 'edit' button [and when clicked ...] should be able to update the values of name, email... etc", but you haven't explained what the problem is with doing this.

Comment: for downvoters, please tell me why downvotes, so that i can correct it, i am beginner in php

Comment: I downvoted and flagged to close because your original question is about a **git merge conflict** issue. The issue has morphed several times. The original tags had **magento** and **svn**. Now it's pdo. You haven't updated the question with more details. You've updated the question with new issues. Your question is way too broad and has too many issues contained within it.

Comment: It looks like PhpBeginner wants to finish an entire project on this question. His last comment on @Reto's answer indicates that. If you have another problem, then please post as a separate question. If your original issue is resolved, please give the bounty to whoever has helped you do that instead of stretching it to another problem within your code on the same question.

Sorry, but if you are yourself not putting in efforts to understand the code you've taken from elsewhere, then that doesn't help.

Comment: Do **not** reuse old questions for a bounty. If you have a new question, **post a new question**. If you can't post a new question, then you can't post a new question, and that's where this ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$uid` is not an user object, so you can not call update on it.
You should first retrieve the user **object** identified by its id from the database und then call update on it.

Additionally, you've got an error in **class.user.php**:

`$stmt = $this->_db->prepare('UPDATE tbl_users SET userName = ?, userEmail = ?, phone = ? WHERE userID = ? ');`

should be:

`$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('UPDATE tbl_users SET userName = ?, userEmail = ?, phone = ? WHERE userID = ? ');`

then in **home.php** you could do something like this:

```
$user_home = new USER();
// query
if ($user_home->update($uname,$email,$phone,$uid)); {
    $user_home->redirect('home.php');
}
```

Another issue is, that you assign the users id to `$_SESSION['userSession']` so you have to change your update function in your **class.user.php**:

```
public function update($uname,$email,$phone) {
    try {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('UPDATE tbl_users SET userName = ?, userEmail = ?, phone = ? WHERE userID = ? ');
    $stmt->execute(array($uname,$email,$phone,$_SESSION['userSession']));
    return $stmt->fetch();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
}
```

And finally (because you are currently not saving the users email etc. in the session) the form on the bottom of **home.php** should look rather like this (now including an edit button):

```html
<script>function toggle() { var can = document.getElementsByName("submit"); for (i = 0; i < can.length; i++) { can[i].style.display = can[i].style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'; }}</script>

<form action="home.php" method="POST">
Name<br>
<input type="text" name="txtuname" value="<?php echo $row['userName'] ?>" /><br>
Email<br>
<input type="text" name="txtemail" value="<?php echo $row['userEmail'] ?>" /><br>
Phone<br>
<input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $row['phone'] ?>" /><br>

<input id="sub" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" style="display:none" />
</form>
<button name="submit" onclick="toggle()">Edit</button>
 
</html>
```

Comment: can you please tell me what code i need to replace with what code or what code i  need to add in which file ?

Comment: i updated as in your answer, now getting error : `Notice: Undefined index: userID in`        $stmt->execute(array($uname,$email,$phone,$_SESSION['userID']));` in class.ur.php, also error 2 : `Fatal error: Call to undefined function redirect() in `redirect('home.php');`

Comment: you can see complete code here :`class.usr.php`:   http://pastebin.com/t3Xyi23G   , home.php : http://pastebin.com/SyPjWFVt

Comment: I updated my answer to address this issue as well - sorry, but I prefer to do the edit right here on SO

Comment: after i used home.php code, i got this error : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in` last line. 

i followed your answer, now once i click on "save", i am not getting any errors, but the values of `name, email, phone` are not displaying , instead this erro :

`<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: txtuname` in line `<input type="text" name="txtuname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['txtuname'] ?>" />`

Comment: complete site files : http://www.filedropper.com/site3

database : http://www.filedropper.com/designer3 , please download these files and help me to update fields from profile page.

Comment: See my updated answer - like this your code works (at least on my machine..)

Comment: now i can able to update values of `form fields` in profile page. once i click on `save` button in profile page, values are updating in db, here instead of editing values directly, once we click on `EDIT` button, than only it should allow to edit `fields & save it`, also please help me to add new fields in `profile page`, example : `tax id, hobbies`....

Comment: Well, so basically your original problems are solved. In order to be able to persist additional fields, you have to add them to your form and extend your update function of the user class accordingly. Concerning your question about the edit functionality: there exist various techniques to enable disable/enable forms.

Comment: no, before also i wanted to `update the values` after clicking `edit` button only, when you get free time, please help me for that...

Comment: Well, just replace the form in your `home.php` with the form from the snippet in my updated answer and voilà - you have also the desired save after edit functionality - **over and out**..

Comment: now i can able to `update` after i click on `EDIT` button, but problem is i want different UI for Edit page : http://prnt.sc/cvrcgs & profile page : http://prnt.sc/cvrci0 , can you please give answer for this.....

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, `$uid` is an integer, either `-1` or the `userID` GET parameter.

Probably you wanted something like

```
$user_home->update( ..., $uid );
```

instead, assuming `$user_home = new USER();` is missing. Or maybe any other instance of `USER` has to be created

```
$another = new USER();
...
$another->update( ..., $uid );
```

Comment: 1) i tried this : `if ($user_home->update($uname,$email,$phone, $uid));`  2) I tried this : `$another = new USER();` , `$another->update( ..., $uid );` & `if ($another->update($uname,$email,$phone,$userID));` , after i tried both now i am getting 2 errors : `err 1: Notice: Undefined property: USER::$_db in line :` , `err2 : Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in` in line `$stmt = $this->_db->prepare('UPDATE tbl_users SET userName = ?, userEmail = ?, phone = ? WHERE userID = ? ');` in class.usr.php file....

Answer (score 1):

Why are you storing all your user info in a Session. User id or user name should be passed in a get variable. You then validate it that it exist if it doesn't no need to keep going kill the script. Redirect to error page or something. Also user should only be allowed to edit if user_id from the session equals get user_id, that means that user visiting current page. Is the owner so he can modify it. The value in your form should be the results from the database. Also you have no email or text input validation. Like a check that makes sure its a real email. A check to make sure text is only letters and numbers when form is submitted.

As far as your error, Where did you declare your object?  I don't see it.

it has to be something like this.

```
$user_home = new USER();
then you can call update like so
$uid = $user_home->update($uname,$email,$phone,$userID);
```

you have an error here

```
 public function update($uname,$email,$phone) { try { $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('UPDATE tbl_users SET userName = ?, userEmail = ?, phone = ? WHERE userID = ? '); $stmt->execute(array($uname,$email,$phone,$_SESSION['userID'‌​])); return $stmt->fetch(); } catch(PDOException $e) { echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>'; } }
```

remove the _ from  db like this

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE tbl_users SET userName = ?, userEmail = ?, phone = ? WHERE userID = ? '
```

Comment: i tried this : `if ($user_home->update($uname,$email,$phone,$userID));` , now i am getting 2 errors : `err 1: Notice: Undefined property: USER::$_db in line :` , `err2 : Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in` in line `$stmt = $this->_db->prepare('UPDATE tbl_users SET userName = ?, userEmail = ?, phone = ? WHERE userID = ? ');` in class.usr.php file....

Comment: YOU HAVE AN ERROR HERE      public function update($uname,$email,$phone) {
        try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('UPDATE tbl_users SET userName = ?, userEmail = ?, phone = ? WHERE userID = ? ');
        $stmt->execute(array($uname,$email,$phone,$_SESSION['userID']));
        return $stmt->fetch();
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }

Comment: HAS TO BE  $stmt = this->db->prepare('UPDATE tbl_users SET userName = ?, userEmail = ?, phone = ? WHERE userID = ? ');

Comment: i am getting errors : `Notice: Undefined property: USER::$db in /` & `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in` in line `$stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE tbl_users SET userName = ?, userEmail = ?, phone = ? WHERE userID = ? ');
`

Comment: complete code : class.usr.php : http://pastebin.com/KfSMqH4V , home.php : http://pastebin.com/KBDdbbjF

Comment: complete site files : http://www.filedropper.com/site2

database : http://www.filedropper.com/designer3 , please download these files and help me to update fields from profile page.

Comment: i can able to edit the fields and save in db , but this should work only after i click `edit` button..... class.user.php : http://pastebin.com/1K5xd17J , home.php : http://pastebin.com/01uxLR6h

Comment: You cant just use someones code and not know whats going on. You have to be able to understand.

Comment: you are absolutely right, in future surely i iwll do that, as i need to finish project soon i am using other code.......

Answer (score 0):

I think i have a quick workaround for your problem, based on the example you have provided and the fact that you might not need to re-write too much code. This is your `home.php` page

```
<?php

//Initializing variable
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect('index.php');
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

Rewrite it like this

```
<?php

//Initializing variable
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

// Fetch user from database based on user id
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// $row will provide the old values stored in database if you want them to be displayed as initial values inside your input fields

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect('index.php');
} else {
// adding this here ensures that the $user_home object exists
require_once("profile.php");
}    
?>
```

Then your `profile.php` page can be like this simple example.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// new data
$uname = $_POST['txtuname'];
$email = $_POST['txtemail'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$userID= $row['userID'];

// query
$user_home->update($uname,$email,$phone,$userID)); 
}

<form action="" method="POST">    
Name<br>
<input type="text" name="txtuname" value="<?php echo $row['userName'] ?>" /><br>
Email<br>
<input type="text" name="txtemail" value="<?php echo $row['userEmail'] ?>" /><br>
Phone<br>
<input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $row['userPhone'] ?>" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: i followed your answer, now i am getting error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on a non-object in ` in line
`$uid->update($uname,$email,$phone,$userID);` in `profile.php file`....  class.usr.php : http://pastebin.com/HiixC2kt , home.php : http://pastebin.com/7v5ttdrm , profile.php :  http://pastebin.com/pSagJBKV

Comment: wrong variable names :) i think now it must do exactly what you want

Comment: Thanks for the update , now there is no error, but values are not saving in database.....

Comment: also i want to save the values into database only after clicking `edit` button, please help me for this....

Comment: have you tried to `echo` or `var_dump` of all `$_POST` variables and `$row['userID']` after submitting the form to see what value they get. Most probably i think you have a `$row['userID']` issue and it is not saving. Are the names of the database fields correct? In my example i used demo field-names, i hope you have not used those of the example exactly and used your database fields.